# onActivityResult, passing an image chosen from Chooser to email questions

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I have the following code to have an app that asks for an email address, a message, has a button to choose an image and a imageButton which should only visible if tha app gets an email address, a message and a file chosen. The file chosen should load in the imageButton.

Once you press the imageButton, which now, displays the image chosen and is visible, the app should open the email application, filling the to address, the body of the message and attach the image chosen.

I have the following code, but I'm not being able to get the image passed to the email app.

Also, I can't verify if the image is loaded in order to make the imageButton visible.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;


import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, TextWatcher {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    EditText message;
    EditText address;
    Button buttonAttach;
    ImageButton buttonSend;
    String mAdress;
    String mMessage;
    private InputStream stream;
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    private ImageView v;
    private Uri uri;
    private boolean image;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailMessage);
        address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.to_address);
        buttonAttach = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choose_button);
        buttonSend = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

        buttonAttach.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(this);

        message.addTextChangedListener(this);

    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //if buttonAttach is pushed, call openGallery method
        if (view == buttonAttach){
            openGallery();
        }
        //if buttonSend is pushed, try to get address, message and image
        if (view == buttonSend){
            try{
                String mAddress = address.getText().toString();
                String mMessage = message.getText().toString();

                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", mAddress, null));

                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mMessage);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

                startActivity(i);
            }
            //if exception is caught, display Toast.
            catch(Throwable th){
                Toast.makeText(this,"Could not send message: " + th.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

    }

    // openGallery method
    private void openGallery() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Intent to provide a chooser to choose a picture.
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose app..."), REQUEST_CODE);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        image = false;

        //if requestCode and resultCode are okay, get data from Intent data
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            // Display Toast stating your choice of file.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You chose the file: " + uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Try to get the stream and set the image.
            try {

                stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                v = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
                v.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

                //if file not found, display Toast saying it could not open file.
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("OnActivityResult", "Could not open file.");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not open file.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }



        image = true;
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }




    @Override
    // After changing text on address or message make image visible.
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String text = message.getText().toString();
        String email = address.getText().toString();
        Log.i("afterTextChanged", "Email is:" + email);
        Log.i("afterTextChanged", "String text is:" + text);
        Animation anim = null;
        View view = findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        boolean valid = text.length() > 0 && email.length() > 0;
        boolean isVisible = view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;

        if (isVisible == valid){
            return;
            }

        if (valid){
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            anim = AnimationUtils.makeInAnimation(this, true);
        }else{
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            anim = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(this, true);
            }
        Log.i("Anim", "Animation starting.");
        view.startAnimation(anim);

    }




    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
            int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What uri did you get? (show string value from logs)

Comment: uri gave me the following path: //media/external/images/media/3141.

Answer (score 1):

Right now in your code you are never assign anything to `uri` MainActivity variable

Because in `onActivityResult` `Uri uri = data.getData();` is local variable so MainActivity.uri is always null

Comment: uri is assigned on the beginning of the activity so it should be available to all the methods.

Comment: but YOU ARE NOT CHANGING this URI when you get `onActivityResult`

Comment: Could you give me a pointer? How can I pass the uri value to the email intent?